# How to find the element in another page and input value from element on current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In an Mvc 5 Bootstrap project I recently managed to solve an issue of inserting the value of one element into another element using jQuery. It enables the user to select between different strings and once selected inserts the string into a textbox in a form element.

You can view the example here: http://www.bootply.com/DPoaz49nSb

This was all very well when all the elements were on the same page (as in the example).

My question now is: HOW would I do this if the elements were on different pages (link on one page then leads the user to a form on another page where the link string is now inserted)? Any help would be much appreciated.

### ADD

Ive tried a couple solutions  like this with the Bootply example but I'm no pro at this so please help if you have any pointers.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = '@Url.Action("NewPageToBeOpened", "ControllerName", new { textValue = "----" })'.replace("----", $('#textBox').val($(this).text());
window.location = url;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as an argument to the url of the second page and when the DOM of the second page would be ready to read this param from the url and set it as the value of the element you want.

Something like this:

```
// You will need this function for getting the parameter's value
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the above function, please have a look [here](http:////%20For%20furtherm%20clarification%20about%20this,%20please%20have%20a%20look%20[here][1]).

```
$(function(){
    var param = getUrlParameter(paramName);
    $("#elementsId").val(param);
});
```

Comment: Had no luck with that approach and not quite sure I understood it in terms of the example I provided @Christos..still not inserting the value. You added a link that is not working if you get a chance to correct it Id gladly take a look.